# setcookie(): Passing null to parameter #7 ($httponly) of type bool is deprecated

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, setcookie, httponly

```
public function csrf_set_cookie()
{
    $expire = time() + $this->_csrf_expire;
    $secure_cookie = (bool) config_item('cookie_secure');

    if ($secure_cookie && ! is_https())
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    setcookie(
        $this->_csrf_cookie_name,
        $this->_csrf_hash,
        $expire,
        config_item('cookie_path'),
        config_item('cookie_domain'),
        $secure_cookie,
        config_item('cookie_httponly')
    );
    log_message('info', 'CSRF cookie sent');

    return $this;
}
```

> Severity: 8192
>
> Message: setcookie(): Passing null to parameter #7 ($httponly) of type > bool is deprecated
>
> Filename: core/Security.php

Comment: I suggest not passing null to that parameter, then. What's your question? The warning seems fairly self-explanatory

Answer (score 2):

As the warning says, you shouldn't be passing `NULL` to the `httponly` argument. You could use NULL-coalescing to pass an intelligent default if it's not defined in your configuration. E.g.:

```
setcookie(
    $this->_csrf_cookie_name,
    $this->_csrf_hash,
    $expire,
    config_item('cookie_path'),
    config_item('cookie_domain'),
    $secure_cookie,
    config_item('cookie_httponly') ?? true 
    # Here ------------------------^
);
```